# Firebase Realtime Database: Most Efficient way to delete an entry by its value? [Admin SDK]

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database

I have an entry in real time database which looks something like this:

```
{
    <RANDOM_FIREBASE_GENERATED_KEY>: value1,
    <RANDOM_FIREBASE_GENERATED_KEY>: value2,
    <RANDOM_FIREBASE_GENERATED_KEY>: value3,
}
```

I am creating these data points using `push`. Now I also want the flexibility to delete these datapoints using the value. [I can assume that these values are going to be unique]

Here's how I was planning to do it:

```
const values = await Server.rdb.ref('path').get();
    const newValues = Object.keys(values).filter(element => element !== 'to_be_filtered_entity');
    await Server.rdb.ref('path').set(newValues);
```

But this would mean that I need to perform the filtering load at my backend server which is not ideal. Can someone tell me an optimized approach to perform this operation?

Comment: Did you see the the documentation on [querying data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries)? Especially `orderByValue()` and `equalTo` seem relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

As per one of the comments, I added

```
"connected-users": {
        "$uid": {
          ".indexOn": ".value",
          ".read":"$uid === auth.uid && auth.token.email_verified === true",
          ".write":"$uid === auth.uid && auth.token.email_verified === true"
        }
      }
```

for the rules and then used:

```
await Server.rdb
      .ref(`${rdb_paths.funfuse_connected_users}/${loc}`)
      .orderByValue()
      .equalTo(<value>)
```

and this solved my issue.